# Checkbox para validación utilizando php o javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Quiero validar un formulario PHP con "checkbox" preferiblemente con Javascript para el campo "Acepto". no recibe "alert("Acepta los términos");".

form.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $de = 'test@gmail.com';
        $asunto = 'Tema de Email';
        $para = $_POST['mail_txt'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nom_txt'];
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensage_txt'];

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$para."\r\n".' Reply-To: '.$para."\r\n".' X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane!</h1>';
        $message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';
        $message .= '</body></html>';


        $check = $_POST['acepto_chk']; 
        if ($check==false)
        {
            echo "Error, Por favor <a href='#'>inténtalo de nuevo</a>"; 
        } else {   
            echo "Gracias por su solicitud nos pondremos en contacto con usted lo antes posible."; 
            mail($de, $asunto, $message, $headers);
        }
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function valid() {

    //Validación de campo vacío
    var checkBox=document.contact_form.acepto_chk

    if (checkBox.value==false){
        alert("Acepta los términos");
        checkBox.focus()
        return false
    }

    return true
}
</script>

<body>

    <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="form.php" onSubmit="return valid()">

        <p>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre<label>   
            <input type="type" name="nom_txt"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email<label> 
            <input type="type" name="mail_txt"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="mensaje">Mensaje<label>
            <textarea name="mensage_txt"></textarea>  
        <p>

        <p>
            <span>Acepto.</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="acepto_chk" id="acepto_chk"/>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por un lado, no estas validando correctamente que el checkbox este marcado en JavaScript y por otro tampoco estas validando la existencia de este campo correctamente en PHP.

**Validacion JS**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function valid() {
    //Validación de campo vacío
    if (document.getElementById("acepto_chk").checked==false){
        alert("Acepta los terminos");
        document.getElementById("acepto_chk").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="acepto_chk" id="acepto_chk" value="1" />
```

**Validacion PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["acepto_chk"]) && $_POST["acepto_chk"] == 1){
    echo "Checkbox seleccionado";
}else{
    echo "Checkbox no seleccionado";
}
?>
```

A modo de prueba de concepto te dejo un ejemplo practico de como validar un checkbox en JS: https://jsfiddle.net/45vu6rfo/2/

Answer (score 0):

Tomando el mismo ejemplo anterior, lo he adaptado a mi código de un formulario propio, ha funcionado muy bien y me ha ayudado a completar la validación que necesitaba para 4 checkbox.

**HTML**

```html
 

<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
<title>Formularios Operativos</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="enviar.php" name="formulario" method="post">
<legend>Encuesta de calidad de servicio</legend>
<fieldset>
<label>L&iacute;neas de Metro:</label>
<input id="linea1" value="linea1" name="metro" tabindex="1" type="checkbox">
<label for="linea1">L&iacute;nea 1</label>
<input id="linea2" value="linea2" name="metro" tabindex="2" type="checkbox">
<label for="linea2">L&iacute;nea 2</label>
<input id="linea3" value="linea3" name="metro" tabindex="3" type="checkbox">
<label for="linea3">L&iacute;nea 3</label> 
<input id="linea4" value="linea4" name="metro" tabindex="4" type="checkbox">
<label for="linea4">L&iacute;nea 4</label>
</fieldset>
<input class="boton1" value="Enviar" tabindex="5" type="submit">
</form>
<script src="js/form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function valida_metro() {

    if ((document.getElementById("linea1").checked==false) && (document.getElementById("linea2").checked==false) && (document.getElementById("linea3").checked==false) && (document.getElementById("linea4").checked==false)){
        alert("Debes seleccionar al menos una opción de línea del metro.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
window.onsubmit = valida_metro;
```

El código de validación JavaScript, evalúa que al menos una casilla esté chequeada, si no lanza un mensaje de alerta en pantalla, interrumpiendo el envío del formulario por completo, hasta que cumpla con chequear una casilla.

Espero que ayude a otros a entender y solucionar de esta manera la validación de checkbox.