# Ayuda boton check box aceptacion condiciones

Tags: php, javascript, html, formularios

tengo un formulario en el que añadi una casilla de verificación con el siguiente código (ver abajo) pero no consigo que funcione, ¿alguien podría por favor indicarme si el código tiene algo mas ?

gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, para que conozcas como usar el sitio  haz el [recorrido de inicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), Ayudaria bastante si agregas directamente código en la pregunta y si obtienes errores en el navegador usar tú código

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Checkbox para validación utilizando php o javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48398/checkbox-para-validaci%c3%b3n-utilizando-php-o-javascript)

Comment: Hola Carmen, bienvenida. Recuerda poner el codigo en formato texto y no como imagen. Para formatearlo puedes usar `ctrl +k` y asi queda *guapo*.  Qué error recibes?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cambiar el evento del input de:

```
onclick="enableSending()"
```

a

```
onchange="enableSending()"
```

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida te recomiendo que leas [**_¿Como Responder?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Deberías dar una explicación de porque cambiar el evento, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto:

```js
function enableSending(){
  let btn = document.getElementById("enviar");
  let checkbox = document.getElementById("terms");
  btn.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

```html
<div class="terms">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onChange="enableSending()">
  <label for="terms">Al enviar este mensaje prestas expresamente consentimiento al tratamiento de sus datos personales. He leido y acepto la <a href="#" targer="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a></label>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar" disabled="disabled">
```

Si te fijas cree un **input** tipo **submit** deshabilitado para probar. Me imagino según tu **js** que estas tratando de habilitar el botón de enviar cuando acepte los **"términos y condiciones"**. El checkbox llama a la función **enableSending** por el evento **change** y no por el **click** ya que los **checkbox** cambian de estado y es mejor evaluarlos por **"cuando cambian de estado o valor"** osea el **change**. Luego en la función **enableSending** invoque el **checkbox** y el **input** por el **id**, tu puedes llamarlo como lo estabas haciendo pero como no especificastes el html de tu formulario me limite agregarle un **id** e invocarlos por ese atributo, pero el efecto deseado es el mismo, te puedes guiar de este ejemplo espero te sirva.

Saludos